# YouTube MediaThumbnail quality in java

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

I want to get the highest quality thumbnail from the ones available while working with VideoEntry in Java.

I'm using the gdata libraries.

I know that the best one is the one with the attribute yt:name="hqdefault" in the xml but I have no idea how to get that attribute value from the MediaThumbnail in code.

There is no method for that in the MediaThumbnail class.

My goal is to use the "hqdefault" one if it's available and if not then use the "default" one.
So far I'm using the first from the thumbnail list, but as I understand it won't necessarily be the "default" one since the list can come in a random order.

Is there any way to find out the quality of the MediaThumbnail without parsing the url?

Answer (score 0):

Following code lists all possible thumbnails for a video. Choose whichever is suitable for you.

```
for (MediaThumbnail mediaThumbnail : VideoEntry.getMediaGroup().getThumbnails()) {
System.out.println(mediaThumbnail.getUrl());
}
```